# stbi_load() return NULL and "PNG not supported: unknown PNG chunk type" error occurred, when load android internal storage file path

Tags: android, c++, stb-image

#### Purpose

I am making an Android application with vulkan. I saved bitmap in "texture.png" file in the device internal storage. I want to show this image with vulkan. Then I need to pass image data to c++ somehow.

#### Try

I tried below process:

- pass the image file path to c++
- load file data from path with stbi_load() (OSS stb_image.h)

#### Error

But stbi_load() return NULL and stb_error message is "PNG not supported: unknown PNG chunk type".

How to fix to load image in android internal storage file?

#### code

outlet of my code.

```kotlin
// create file path (kotlin)
val filePath: String = File(context.filesDir, "texture.png").path
```

```cpp
// load image file (c++)

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

void loadImage(const std::string filePath) {// same as ↑ filePath

    int width, height, channels;
    auto* pImage = stbi_load(filePath.c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, 0);

    if (pImage == nullptr) {
        return;// I'm here.
    }
    // (some successive process)
}
```

Comment: you wrote 'bitmap in "texture.png"'. Are you sure that it is a valid PNG file? Maybe it is something else (a usual BMP file?)

Comment: @KoVadim I tried to check it. But I couldn't find no way to check the content type of the file in android framework. There exists only the way to check file extension.

Comment: stbi has a function "stbi_failure_reason()" that provides a reason for the error. by the way, you could open a file as a binary file and check 2-3 first bytes. usually, it is very simple to guess the file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the alternative to pass image data to c++.

#### before

I tried and give up this.

- filePath->stbi_load()->iamge data(unsigned char*)

#### after

It is working very well. I can show the file image with vulkan now.

- bitmap->AndroidBitmap_getInfo()->iamge data(unsigned char*).

code outlet

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_yourproject_NativeAPI_loadBitmap(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject bitmap) {
    AndroidBitmapInfo androidBitmapInfo;
    AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &androidBitmapInfo);
    void* pixels;// image data.
    AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
    
    ・
    ・
    ・
    // For example, copy image data to vulkan image memory.
    void* p;
    vkMapMemory(device, imageMemory, 0, VK_WHOLE_SIZE, 0, &p);
    memcpy(p, pixels, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, imageMemory);
}
```

Don't forget to link *jnigraphics* in CMakeList.txt!